# Ksoap2 - session handling

Tags: android, session, ksoap2

Is there a way to handle sessions with ksoap2 on Android?

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the .call-method returns "CookieJar with any cookies sent by the server".